Is there an integrated or 3rd party fuzzy Window finder in Windows (OS)?
I want to press a key combination like ALT+TAB but instead of switching through every window looking for the right one i want to type the window title or part of it (e.g. explorer / firefox, etc.) to fuzzy search for the window I want.
Does a tool like this exist for Windows?

This question is better suited for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

While superuser is not a place for recommendations for software, you might want to try Windows Powertoys. You can use alt and space to open a tool called "Powertoys Run" which allows you to do a few things. One of them lets you choose an active window by typing < followed by the search for the window you want.
